# Template class: No default constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I know there are a million posts about this, but I still can't figure out why this isn't working =/

this line:

```
test = new Test2<Test>;
```

gives me this error:

```
error C2512: 'Test2<PARENT>' : no appropriate default constructor available
with
[
    PARENT=Test
]
```

code:

```
template<class PARENT>
class Test2;

////////////////////////////

class Test
{
public:
    Test2<Test> *test;

    Test()
    {
        test = new Test2<Test>;
    }
};

/////////////////////////////

template<class PARENT>
class Test2
{
public:
    PARENT *parent;
};

////////////////////////////
```

can someone help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the point of instantiation (i.e. inside the `Test` constructor), all the compiler has so far is a *forward declaration* of `Test2<>`; it doesn't yet know what constructors are available.

To solve, either move the definition of `Test2<>` *before* that of `Test`, or move the definition of the `Test` constructor outside the class definition (and *after* the definition of `Test2<>`).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I was under the impression that after a forward declaration, the members of that class would also be available immediately after it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, your code gives (correctly, IMHO) the error:

```
invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Test2<Test>'
```

This is with g++ 4.5.1. At the point you say:

```
test = new Test2<Test>;
```

Test2 has not been defined, only forward declared.

Comment: I believe the error should be `no appropriate default constructor available` as before creating a class for Test2, it should need a constructor for Test. May be I'm worng. Any comments?

Answer (score -1):

The line `test = new Test2<Test>;` is executing inside default constructor of Test.
And this line will call the default constructor/constructor with no arguments. The constructor of Test is still not complete when the mentioned statement is being called.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: How does compiler know about Test then?

Comment: It doesn't need to.  `Test2<T>` only has a `T *` member, which doesn't need a class definition, only a declaration.